# How can I deserialize a Json file with a header and details in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms, deserialization

```
{
    "id": "007",
    "name": "James Bond",
    "missions": [{
        "year": "2006",
        "title": "Casino Royale"
    },
    {
        "year": "2008",
        "title": "Quantum of Solace"
    },
    {
        "year": "2012",
        "title": "Skyfall"
    },
    {
        "year": "2015",
        "title": "Spectre"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: 
https://components.xamarin.com/view/json.net

With this Libary it is really easy

You can deserialize:

```
JamesBondObject oResult = (JamesBondObject) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sResponse, typeof( JamesBondObject ) );


class JamesBondObject {
    int id;
    string name;
    Mission[] missions;
}

class Mission {
    int year;
    string title;
}
```

Comment: There isn't  generic `DeserializeObject`? eg. `JamesBondObject oResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JamesBondObject>(JamesBondObject);`